# Calculate the page table size and inverted page table size

Tags: memory, pagination, operating-system

In an operating system quiz there was this question:

Calculate the size of the normal and inverted page table, assuming you have a 32-bit architecture with 4GB of RAM and 4KB frame.

What are the calculations to be done?

Answer (score -1):

normal page table ..

32 bit system... = 2^32

size of 1 page/ frame... 4kb = 2^14

no of entries in 1 page table = 2^32/2^14 = 2^18

size of page table = size of 1 entry* no of entries

assuming 1 entry size as 4 bytes... as 32 bits make 4 bytes

so page size= 2^18*2^2=2^20

that is 1 MB

Comment: Size of 1 page/frame = 4KB = 2^12